# How to replace only first matching block using sed command

Tags: bash, sed

I have 2 files and would like to replace the 1st matching block of text from file1 (matching criteria start indicator as **<<EOF** and End of block criteria is **EOF**) with sed from another file2 data.

Example:

**file1**

```
resource "policy" "temp1" { 
 policy = << EOF
 {
  policy1-data
 }
 EOF
}

resource "policy" "temp2" { 
 policy = << EOF
 {
  policy2-data
 }
 EOF
}
```

**file2**

```
{
  modified-policy-data
}
```

**output file**

```
resource "policy" "temp1" { 
 policy = << EOF
 {
  modified-policy-data
 }
 EOF
}

resource "policy" "temp2" { 
 policy = << EOF
 {
  policy2-data
 }
 EOF
}
```

I tried below sed command but that replaces all occurrences of matching criteria in **file1** from **file2** data where I would like to replace **only first matching block occurrence** and rest keep same as is from **file1**

```
lead='<<EOF'
tail='EOF'
sed -nie '/'"$lead"'/ { p r file2 :a n /'"$tail"'/ { p b } ba }p' file1
```

Comment: What is the **actual** command you tried? The one you show is not valid sed syntax.

Comment: nit-pick - `head` rather than `lead` is usually used as the opposite of `tail`, using `lead` instead of `head` might cause some confusion at some point, especially given how similar they are.

Answer (score 1):

Not `sed` but if `ed` is available/acceptable with your given input/data, something like:

The `script.ed` name it to your own hearts content.

```
0r file2
kx
2m/^.*<< EOF/;/^.*EOF/;?[ ]*{?
+1d
1,'xd
,p
Q
```

---

Now run

```
ed -s file1 < script.ed
```

---

Output

```
resource "policy" "temp1" { 
 policy = << EOF
 {
  modified-policy-data
 }
 EOF
}

resource "policy" "temp2" { 
 policy = << EOF
 {
  policy2-data
 }
 EOF
}
```

---

In *one-line*

```
printf '%s\n' '0r file2' 'kx' '2m/^.*<< EOF/;/^.*EOF/;?[ ]*{?' '+1d' "1,'xd" ,p Q | ed -s file
```

---

with variables in a shell script, something like:

file1

```
resource "policy" "temp1" { 
 policy = << EOF
 {
  policy1-data
 }
 EOF
}

resource "policy" "temp2" { 
 policy = << EOF
 {
  policy2-data
 }
 EOF
}
```

file2

```
{
  modified-policy-data
}

foo
bar
baz
```

The script.

```
#!/bin/sh

lead='<< EOF'
tail='EOF'

ed -s file1 <<-EOD
  0r file2
  kx
  2m/^.*$lead/;/^.*$tail/;?[ ]*{?
  +1d
  1,'xd
  ,p
  Q
EOD
```

---

OTOH, your data/files/input looks like `tcl`

---

- Change `Q` to `w` if *in_place* editing is needed.
- Remove the `,p` to silence the output.
- See GNU [ed](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html)
- See POSIX [ed](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html)

Comment: this seems to break if file2 does not contain 3 lines

Comment: `printf '/<< EOF/r file2\n,.p\n/EOF/,$p\nQ\n'  | ed -s file1` ?

Comment: `printf '%s\n' '/<< EOF/r file2' '.+;/EOF/-d' ,p Q  | ed -s file1`

Comment: that does allow replacing Q with w but anything that uses `+` can break: eg. if file1 initially has no lines between lead and tail

Comment: Good catch! got me thinking...

Comment: `printf '%s\n' '/<< EOF/r file2' '.t.' '.;/EOF/-1d' ,p Q  | ed -s file1`  ?

Comment: looks good to me!

Answer (score 1):

Once you match `lead` you must never start a new cycle (ie. `b`)

```
sed -nie '
  p
  /'"$lead"'/ {
    r file2

    :a
    n
    /'"$tail"'/ ! ba

    :b
    p
    n
    bb
  }
' file1
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `awk` would be easier than `sed`.  Something like:

```
awk '! seen && /<< EOF$/ { seen=1; print; 
    while( (getline < "file2") > 0 ) { print } 
    while( (getline > 0) && ! /EOF/ ); } 1' file1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk and aligning the new text with the existing `EOF`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR == FNR {
    new = (NR>1 ? new ORS : "") $0
    next
}
cnt == 1 {
    if ( index($0,tail) ) {
        indent = $0
        sub(/[^[:space:]].*/,"",indent)
        gsub(ORS,ORS indent,new)
        print indent new ORS $0
        cnt++
    }
    next
}
index($0,lead) {
    cnt++
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -v lead='<< EOF' -v tail='EOF' -f tst.awk file2 file1
resource "policy" "temp1" {
 policy = << EOF
 {
   modified-policy-data
 }
 EOF
}

resource "policy" "temp2" {
 policy = << EOF
 {
  policy2-data
 }
 EOF
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU csplit):

```
csplit -s file1 '/EOF/+1' '%EOF%' && cat xx00 file2 xx01 > file3 && rm xx??
```

Use csplit to split file1 into two and remove the text to replaced by file2.

Concatenate the files above with the replacement file sandwiched between them.

Alternative using GNU sed:

```
sed -ne '/EOF/!{p;b};p;:a;n;//!ba;e cat file2' -e ':b;p;n;bb' file1
```

Clean up unwanted files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify which section to replace by resource name, you could do it like this with GNU `sed` and a bash function:

```
repl file1 file2 temp1
```

Where `repl` is defined as:

```
repl() {
  sed -E '
    # Always keep 2 lines in pattern space
    N
    /resource.*"'$3'".*\n.*<< *EOF/ {
      p
      :a
      /^ *EOF$/! {
        N
        s/.*\n//
        ba
      }
      r '$2'
      N
    }
    P
    D' "$1"
}
```

Testing:

```
repl file1 file2 temp1
```

Output:

```
resource "policy" "temp1" {
 policy = << EOF
{
  modified-policy-data
}
 EOF
}

resource "policy" "temp2" {
 policy = << EOF
 {
  policy2-data
 }
 EOF
}
```

Or replace `temp2`:

```
repl file1 file2 temp2
```

Output:

```
resource "policy" "temp1" {
 policy = << EOF
 {
  policy1-data
 }
 EOF
}

resource "policy" "temp2" {
 policy = << EOF
{
  modified-policy-data
}
 EOF
}
```